# Where in Azure can i set the email address to receive emails if an App Service crashes?

Tags: azure

I want to change the email address if an app service fails in Azure

The email looks like:

```
 From: Microsoft Azure <azure-noreply@microsoft.com> 
 Sent: Monday, March 4, 2022 2:20 PM
 To: Admin User <admin.user@company.com>
 Subject: Your app, my-app-service, crashed because of an unhandled exception
   <body>
```

There are no Alerts on  the app , so is this a system wide setting ?
If so how can i change it ?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. Could it be the [subscription contact email](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/change-azure-account-profile)?

Comment: would this be a possibility https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/notifications#:~:text=Configure%20email%20notifications,-To%20review%20the&text=On%20the%20left%2Dhand%20side,on%20the%20top%2Dhand%20navigation.

Comment: I think this could be configured in an "action group" for Azure Monitor Alerts. IIRC, there are (were?) other places this kind of alert might be configured, too.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes,your approach is correct.
- If you have registered your application using Azure AD, then you can Configure email services in the Azure ActiveDirectory window.
- When you make a modification to the notification settings, they are changed for the entire managed domain.
- If you don't have the permissions to edit Azure AD DS resource,  Contact a global administrator to get permissions.
- Go to Azure Portal => **Azure AD Domain Services** => Select ***managed domain***=> **Notification settings**.
  enter the email address in the additional recipients table= > Save